# Find articles where array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I am currently storing tags in the database as a string of arrays

I want to find articles based on the array

```
Article.find_by(tags: 'xbox')
```

But this brings an error.

Also:

```
Article.where(tags: 'xbox')
```

This tells me that I have to insert `{}` to find arrays so

```
Article.where(tags: '{xbox}')
```

This doesn't bring any errors but it doesn't find anything either

```
#=> #<Article id: 4, name: "Playstation 3", price: 150.0, description: "testing description and tags", created_at: "2015-07-06 21:29:24", updated_at: "2015-07-06 21:29:24", user_id: 1, category_id: 2, puerto_rico_city_id: 1, tags: ["", "playstation 3", "playstation", "xbox", "test"]>
```

if I do

```
Article.where(tags: '{"", "playstation 3", "playstation", "xbox", "test"}')
```

This will find it, but I just want it to find it when you type just one of the arrays.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this:

`Article.where('tags @> ?', '{xbox}')`

this will find every `Article` with a tag of `xbox`.

EDIT:

here's a different syntax which does the same:

`Article.where(['? = ANY (tags)', 'xbox'])`